# Setting command color?

Tags: linux, command-line, colors, prompt

I'd like to set my command line colors in a way that the command I type is in different color than everything else.

This is my current `PS1` setup:
`PS1="\n\[\e[1;33m\]\w\[\e[1;30m\] \D{%F %T}\[\e[0m\]\n\W $ \[\e[1;35m\] "`

It gives:

[image]

What I'd like to achieve is to have only `ls -al` in purple (and not everything that follows).

Answer (score 0):

According to Bash's manual:

> **PS0**
>   The  value  of  this  parameter is expanded (see **PROMPTING** below)
>   and displayed by interactive shells after reading a command and before
>   the command is executed.

Thus you can use `PS0` to choose the color output while `PS1` fixes the command prompt. For example using your `PS1` and the following `PS0`

```bsh
PS1="\n\[\e[1;33m\]\w\[\e[1;30m\] \D{%F %T}\[\e[0m\]\n\W $ \[\e[1;35m\] "
PS0="\[\e[0m\]"
```

will result in a purple command prompt and a standard white color output. Please note that commands with builtin color output overwrite the color fixed by `PS0`.

Alternatively you can use [`tput`](https://linux.101hacks.com/ps1-examples/prompt-color-using-tput/) to set colors in `PS0`. Here is an example using `tput` to set command output to white:

```bsh
PS0="\[$(tput setaf 7)\]"
```

This is a Bash-based answer but I believe that the others shells also use `PS1` and `PS0`.

Comment: Thanks. This PS0 setting gives me two strange looking signs each time command is executed. `$ ls -al
☺☻total 44...` A white smiley, and a black smiley!

Comment: That is weird, I do not have such a behavior. Are you observing the problem with other `PS0` ? `PS0=""` or `PS0="\[\e[0;0m\]"` as examples?

Comment: Not with `PS0=""`, but yes with others. I added some spaces `PS0="   "` and this is also OK.

Comment: Have you tried with another terminal emulator?

Comment: No, stuck with Windows+Cygwin+bash.

Comment: Alternatively you can try using `tput` to set the color:  `PS0="\[$(tput setaf 7)\]"` (7 is the white color code).

Comment: Tried `PS0="\[$(tput setaf 7)\]"`, but seems not to work at all (no color change), and also gives two smileys as above.

Comment: It looks like it is a Cygwin issue which misinterprets the color codes. Not idea how to fix it.

Comment: The colour codes that you have hardwired are wrong.  You are turning on boldface with SGR 1.  _Boldface means boldface_ nowadays, not a colour change.  The method using the command substitutions should be explained _first_, because it does not hardwire stuff that is incorrect for the majority of modern terminal types.

Comment: @JdeBP thanks for the heads up but I did not understand why it is incorrect for the majority of modern terminals.